# Gesture Recognizer bug only in iPhone 4.0 and 4.1

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

The following code works in 4.2 & 4.3 but in 4.0 & 4.1 the value comes up as NaN, but only in the UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded case. It shows the correct value in UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged

```
- (void)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
  CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self];
  switch ( [gestureRecognizer state] ) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
      NSLog(@"panChanged - touchPoint = %f", touchPoint.x); // Always works
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
      NSLog(@"panEnded - touchPoint = %f", touchPoint.x); // Always outputs nan
}
```

not sure if this is a bug on apples part or if I'm doing something wrong. Please advise

Comment: You have no break statement in your switch.  Is that intentional?

Comment: yea i took out some code just for demonstration purposes. my original code does indeed have break statements. good catch though :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my own code, I never checked the coordinates in the Begin/End states.  I just treated them as separate events, no related to the position on the screen.  In the End case I assume the last coordinates sent by Changed.  And in the Begin case I cannot trust the coordinates because they were determined after the gesture moved a little and the gesture began, so I ask my tap recognizer where the initial coordinates were.

I suspect that this was the original intent, that Changed be used, but in 4.2 and 4.3 they started filling in the final coordinates for End as well, just to be consistent.